# how to call ajax on frontend of wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In my plugin folder I have two file 
1. hello-ajax.php
2. myajax.js

and by shortcode I add this form on frontend

```
<form id="theForm" method="post">
    <input id="name" name="name" value = "name" type="text" />
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook" />&nbsp; <!-- this puts the action the_ajax_hook into the serialized form -->
    <input id="submit_button" value = "Click This" type="button" onClick="submit_me();" />
</form>
<div id="response_area">
    This is where we\'ll get the response
</div>
```

In plugin file I added js file as:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

// THE AJAX ADD ACTIONS
add_action( 'wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function' ); // need this to serve non logged in users

// THE FUNCTION
function the_action_function(){
    /* this area is very simple but being serverside it affords the possibility of retreiving data from the server and passing it back to the javascript function */
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo"Hello World, " . $name;// this is passed back to the javascript function
    die();// wordpress may print out a spurious zero without this - can be particularly bad if using json
}
// ADD EG A FORM TO THE PAGE
```

So form is displaying at front end but in console `Uncaught ReferenceError: submit_me is not defined`

`submit_me()` is defined in myajax.js file as:

```
function submit_me(){
    //alert(a);
    jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, jQuery("#theForm").serialize()
    ,
    function(response_from_the_action_function){
        jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
    }
    );
}
```

But this function is not working, and as far i know there is some problem in ajax call, so suggest me what did I wrong and how to make it work....Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `ready` handler?

Answer (score 3):

Thought I should mention this so someone can avoid wasting 2 hours like I did.
If you are attempting ajax from the front end but you have a plugin that that disables admin (backend) access to logged in users then there is a problem.
To solve, I got the following code from [everthere](http://everthere.com/how-to-fix-wordpress-admin-ajax-php-302-redirection-error/).
Add this to your functions.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='AJAXfunctionCall'):
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
endif;
```

Where AJAXfunctionCall is your function responding to the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that function `submit_me()` isn't included into `$(document).ready()` handler.  The function is not visible from the global scope and thus cannot be called from the `onclick` property.

Also, the correct way to include scripts in wordpress is by hooking into `wp_enqueue_scripts` action:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_your_scripts');
function enqueue_your_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}
```