# Path for ajax url in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How to call an ajax url in wordpress. Through  a javascript file

I was using  http://example.com/site/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/upload.php..

This is working but now I have changed the structure.

Now I  want to make a call to a function inside a class

```
e.g
class A{


    function xyz(){
    include('upload.php');
    }
    }
```

Now, I am not calling upload.php through the javascript file but loading it inside the xyz function in the class.

So I want a way to call the xyz function from the javascript file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read this link http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. Do you need to register wordpress hook wp_ajax.

Add to your php code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_xyz', array($this, 'xyz') );
```

In javascript

```
var data = {
    action: 'xyz'
};
// since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this questions:

1. [how to call ajax on frontend of wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059434/how-to-call-ajax-on-frontend-of-wordpress)
2. [Wordpress: how to call a plugin function with an ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908823/wordpress-how-to-call-a-plugin-function-with-an-ajax-call)

And i think [Getting Started with AJAX & WordPress Pagination](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination--wp-23099) helps you too.